# Configure white lines width in barcode for zbar

Tags: android, zbar

I have code39 barcode

[image]

Zbar scan this without troubles, but if i have black frame around barcode
[image]

Zbar кecognizes the frame as part of a barcode

Can i configure white line width in scanner config to avoid this ?

Comment: Barcodes have a check in the end that tells that what was read is valid or not, I don't think that the frame is creating an issue, because the scanner will fail the check

Comment: Are you getting an error? or invalid data? or no data at all ?